# Global menu hides window decorator from startup applications

Tags: unity, appmenu, window-buttons, startup-applications

I am using 11.10 with Unity. When I set e.g. thunderbird as startup application, it will start just after login, but it will be not maximized placed with its window decorators just beneath the global menu, so I am not able to move the window down. I don't know where to search on launchpad for that. Is it just me having these troubles?

BTW: I also enabled the proposed update repo.

Comment: Another workaround is to open window menu with Alt+Space. Hope that helps.

Comment: @brubelsabs  - I can't reproduce your problem so I cant really help as such.  Maybe introducing a delay in starting thunderbird could help e.g. `bash -c 'sleep 15 && thunderbird'` as a startup command line could help?

Comment: Why didn't you made answer out of this? This is the most useful answer so far, since it works without any user interaction. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>converted comment to answer</sub>

I can't reproduce your problem - however the following may help:

Running applications through the *Startup Applications* GUI can sometimes be problematic - the GUI interface is being loaded at the same time as the applications specified in the *Startup Applications*.

Occasionally you can get unfortunate interactions such as your Thunderbird observation.

In my-case, I have *pidgin* or *empathy* started through the GUI but these applications did not display correctly.

The workaround I used was to introduce a short delay to allow the Unity/Gnome-Shell interface to be brought-up fully before *pidgin* or *empathy* was started.

Can I suggest you try something similar for *Thunderbird* - for the *Startup-Applications* command line entry `thunderbird` change this to:

```
bash -c 'sleep 15 && thunderbird'
```

The command delays the startup of thunderbird by 15 seconds - if it works for you experiment with reducing the `sleep 15` value to give you the optimum shortest delay for starting *Thunderbird*.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I have just figured out that if you expand the window by dragging the left down corner to the left down on the screen, the window decorator will appear again. This is not a solution to your problem, so I hope someone comes up with a fix very soon. It annoys me ever other minute.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the main part of your question, which appears to be a bug, but to move windows when the window decorators can't be reached, you can keep Alt pressed and then drag the window around.